# How can I get the variable name of a variable using php?

Tags: drupal

I have a drupal template. I want to know what are the names of the active variables using php..
How do I achieve that ?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question. What larger problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to get which variables have been defined, you can use PHP's function `get_defined_vars`:

```
print_r(get_defined_vars());
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php

Answer (score 0):

If your after Drupals globals, here they are...

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/globals/7